# How to make onClickListner in TextView and how to fetch json url if click in textview means data will appear to next page

Tags: java, android

I am trying if `Textview` clicked means `json` url is Display in another page

This is my Dashboard.java

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {


    public static TextView tvclick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        tvclick =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvstudent);

        tvclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this, Jsondata.class);
                intent.putExtra("text", tvclick.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
            }
    }
```

This AsyncTask class

```
public class Jsondata extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    String tvclick;

    Student student=new Student();
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url=new URL("http://ismspro.ibridgellc.in/api/test/login");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line="";
            while(line != null) {
                        line =bufferedReader.readLine();
                        tvclick= tvclick + line;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Dashboard.tvclick.setText((CharSequence) student.tvstudent);
    }
}
```

I am trying if Textview clicked means json url is Display in Student.java page(inside Textview)

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: I am trying json url data is appear another page while clicking textview .